# Access Security Lock Out

Tags: security, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I work for a company that has an Access program that they bought the source code (the company they bought the software from no longer exist or I would contact them). I was asked modify the database to add in a couple features and add a query. I modified the source .accdb file to put in the modifications for a client since that was the only way to get the modification done and used MS Office 2010. However when I copy it to their server and try to open it in 2007 it is locked down.

Is there a reason for this and what can I do to unlock the program?  I have used Google to search for this information and cannot find anything helpful to unlock the database or find out why this could be happening.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn602608%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: check the library references (from the VBA Editor: Tools->References).  If any start with "MISSING", you need to uncheck them and replace them with available versions.

Comment: What does `locked down` mean?